# Export/import content with full revision history mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

In mediawiki, I am trying to migrate content from one wikisite to another wikisite. I want to import the content so that the changes appears exactly the same as recent changes, for example, if userA changed page x in date x, I want to export the change to the other wiki so that the change appear in the same user and date.

Doing it by using scripts does not respect the recent-changes history for user and date.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [export](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Export)/[import](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Import)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [wiki-family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family) with prefixes. I have recently done this, and it works really well!

The idea is, that you use ONE database, for both wikis. You can then these parameters, to share the relevant tables:

```
$wgDBprefix         = 'theOneWiki_'
$wgSharedPrefix     = 'shared_'
$wgSharedTables = array( 'user', 'user_properties', 'user_groups', 'user_former_groups', 'user_newtalk' );
```

This way you can share the tables, that hold the change-info.

Best regards,
Max